# docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://localhost:2375. Is the docker daemon running?

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I've really tried tons of solvings but nothing work for me . Maybe because I use WSL for window (ubuntu 18.04) , but I'm not sure . Pls if someone solved this issue . let me know

[image]

My ubuntu data:

[image]

I've used this tutorial for installation, but also earlier I was using official tutorial , but it give me the same issue:

https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-and-use-docker-on-ubuntu-18-04/

Comment: What is the value of `$DOCKER_HOST` and if it is set, how did it get set?

Comment: Important security disclaimer, listening on port 2375 is a security vulnerability in most scenarios. It allows anyone with access to that port root access on the host. At best, this is only a local privilege of any local non-privileged user to the root user without a password.

Comment: @BMitch that's the listening port docker swarm mode uses, I mean, it's not something Andrey had configured.

Comment: @yzT swarm mode listens on 2377. 2375 is the unencrypted API port to the docker engine without any credentials or client verification.

Comment: @yzT by default, docker will not listen on this port. Some vendors change this configuration in specific scenarios where only trusted processes can be run on the same network (e.g. CI build servers in single purpose ephemeral VMs).

Comment: my bad there, similar ports :)

Comment: echo $DOCKER_HOST = tcp://localhost:2375 , I think I set it , I was looking for some solving and have found to set  this value like this

Comment: what should I set ? can you help pls ?

Comment: Generally you should `unset DOCKER_HOST` unless you have a really specific reason to think you need it.

Comment: I've done it , but I see the same issue

Comment: Can't be the same issue since the value was in your error message.

Comment: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.

Comment: is it change something ? do you have solving for this one ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is most likely that you are trying to use docker as a standard user who doesn't belong to the docker group, instead as root.

First, check whether the service is indeed running with `systemctl status docker.service`.

If the service is running, try to run the same container, but as `root`.

If it's working as root, then just add your user to the docker group, and that's it. `usermod -a -G docker andreyradkevich`

Comment: System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate. add this issue after executing this command systemctl status docker.service

Comment: @AndreyRadkevich hmm that's due to WSL. I'm afraid I can't help you with that, as I'm not a WSL user, but there should be something similar to `systemctl`, `upstart` or whatever that let you manage a service (start, stop, status, etc)